# Is there a way to create an "Orphan" Excel instance for a specific workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

**Situation**: Currently, I am able to create a new instance of Excel, assign the current open workbook to that instance and close the old instance; however, when opening other Excel workbooks, they are all being assigned to the new instance I created.

**Goal/Reason**: I am seeking to understand how I can prevent other workbooks from being opened in the new instance. The reason for this need is that there are certain edits that I would like to make in order to only affect one instance of Excel and not the others, hence the term "Orphan" instance.

**Update**: I did learn that if I do not include the code to quit the application, then any workbooks I open are assigned to the old instance. This was the closest I could get to my goal; however in this situation I would need to remove that old instance.

```
Sub SaveCloseReOpen()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application              'Create a new instance of Excel.

xlApp.Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.FullName     'Open the current workbook in that instance.

xlApp.displayStatusBar = False                 'Hide the status bar of the new instance.
xlApp.displayFormulaBar = False                'Hide the formula bar of the new instance.

xlApp.Visible = True                           'Display the instance.
Set xlApp = Nothing                            'Set variable to nothing.

Application.DisplayAlerts = False              'Turn off alerts.
ThisWorkbook.Save                              'Save current workbook.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True               'Turn on alerts.
Application.Quit                               'Close previous instance application.

End Sub
```

Comment: Then open a third instance (`xlApp2`). Would you care to explain in more detail why you would need such a task?

Comment: You haven't really explained the order of things, and what you are typically doing. Where are other workbooks being opened in the code above??

Comment: You realise you can prefix every workbooks.open call by an application object? Create multiple applications, and control which app opens workbooks: xlApp1.Workbooks.Open(...), xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(...), xlApp3.Workbooks.Open(...)

Comment: Why do you need more than one instance of Excel? Also, you will only be able to open a workbook read only in the second instance if you have it open read/write in the first.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I might be overcomplicating my code, but what I am trying to do overall is disable the formula and status bar of my workbook in my Excel application without affecting other open workbooks. That is where I decided to put my workbook in its own Excel instance and not affect others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change Application Properties When Activating a Workbook

**NEW**

- It's kind of a madhouse, but maybe you will find it useful.
- It will create the VBScript file `SCRO.vbs` in the workbooks folder, to be run to open the workbook in another instance. Then it will close the workbook in this instance.
- Additionally still use the `Workbook_Deactivate` procedure to not end up with invisible bars.
- I would personally stick with the first solution since I still don't see any benefits of the new instance.
- If this doesn't work or gives you any trouble, your feedback will be most appreciated since it's kind of out of my league (there may be consequences I'm not aware of).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveCloseReOpen()
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    Dim vbsPath As String: vbsPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "SCRO.vbs"
    Dim vbsContents As String: vbsContents = vbsOpenFileInNewInstance(FilePath)
    writeToTextFile vbsPath, vbsContents
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run vbsPath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
    
Function vbsOpenFileInNewInstance( _
    ByVal FilePath As String) _
As String
    Dim S As String
    S = S & "openFileInNewInstance """ & FilePath & """" & vbLf
    S = S & "Sub openFileInNewInstance(FilePath)" & vbLf
    S = S & "    With CreateObject(""Excel.Application"")" & vbLf
    S = S & "        .Visible = True" & vbLf
    S = S & "        .Workbooks.Open FilePath" & vbLf
    S = S & "        .DisplayStatusBar = False" & vbLf
    S = S & "        .DisplayFormulaBar = False" & vbLf
    S = S & "        Exit Sub" & vbLf
    S = S & "    End With" & vbLf
    S = S & "End Sub"
    vbsOpenFileInNewInstance = S
    Debug.Print S
End Function

Sub writeToTextFile( _
        ByVal FilePath As String, _
        ByVal WriteString As String)
    Dim Num As Long: Num = FreeFile()
    Open FilePath For Output As #Num
    Print #Num, WriteString
    Close #Num
End Sub
```

**OLD**

- You could use the workbook events.
- Copy the following code into the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this information. I have tried this method, however the status and formula bars are visible after I deactivate the workbook. Is there a way we can keep them hidden even after deactivating the workbook?

Comment: Remove the code from `Workbook_Deactivate`. Maybe add it to `Workbook_BeforeClose` and the first one to `Workbook_Open`. But then what does this *"without affecting other open workbooks"* mean?

Comment: Right, what I mean by that is I would like to remove the status and formula bars for only one workbook, but as soon as I do that, it removes it for all the other open workbooks. That is why I wanted to assign my workbook to a separate “orphan” Excel instance, which would not affect other workbooks.

Comment: The provided solution (code) is doing what you're saying in your most recent comment. I have it open now: when I select the workbook containing this code, it hides the bars and as soon as I select another workbook, it shows them again.

Comment: Right, but it will also show the bars in the workbook that was deactivated. I’m looking to see if there is a way to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Then another instance is the way to go. But I don't understand why you have to quit the initial `Application`?

Comment: I’m quitting the application to make sure that only one copy of my workbook is showing. Actually, as I am thinking about it, would it be possible that after I quit the ```Application``` I can assign new workbooks to that instance?

Comment: You cannot after you quit it. This solution will toggle the visibility. So I don't understand what harm could be done to the workbook by showing the bars when it is deactivated and hiding them again when it is activated?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Just to clarify, would there be a way to make sure my workbook opens in the "xlApp” instance and other workbooks in the Application instance?

Comment: Right, but if I won’t quit the initial Application, my code will create two visible copies of my workbook. Can I assign my workbook to the “xlApp” instance before being assigned to the initial Application?

Comment: My last comment was full of it. As soon as you quit the initial `Application`, the `xlApp` will also be destroyed; the same will happen if you close the workbook in the initial `Application`: you will wait until the workbook becomes read/write and the `xlApp` will quit after you press `Read/write`. So I don't think that using another instance is possible without starting it from another workbook.

Comment: Thank you for the updated material, I found this very helpful and appreciate you taking the time to help me with this.